# Convergent sum of an Harmonic-like series

Tags: real-analysis

Let $b$ be an integer greater than $1$ and let $d$ be a digit $0\leq d<b$. Let $A$ denote the set of all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that its $b$-adic expansion of $k$ fails to contain the digit $d$. If $a_k=1/k$ for $k\in A$ and $a_k=0$ otherwise, prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k<\infty$.

I would appreciate if someone can give a *hint* on how to prove this statement. I have done the following but I can't see a clear relation to bound the sum from above. The $b$-adic expansion of a natural number $n$ is

$$
n= \sum_{j=0}^p r_jb^j,
$$

where $0\leq r_j< b$ and $r_p\neq 0$. Now, for $p$ fixed, there are $(b-1)^{p+1}$ numbers that fail to contain digit $d$. Moreover they form an incrasing sequence as

$$
k_1^{(p=0)}<k_2^{(p=0)}<\dots<k_{b-1}^{(p=0)}<k_1^{(p=1)}<\dots <k_{(b-1)^2}^{p=1}<\dots
$$

This means that the partial sums $S_m = \sum_{k=1}^m a_k$ are strictly increasing. Obviously if $S_m<|M|$ for $M$ fixed, the series would converge by monotone convergence. However, I can't find such $M$. Another option could be to bound the sum as

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{1}{k_1^{(p=0)}}+\frac{1}{k_2^{(p=0)}}+\dots+\frac{1}{k_{b-1}^{(p=0)}}+\frac{1}{k_1^{(p=1)}}+\dots+\frac{1}{k_{(b-1)^2}^{(p=0)}}+\dots \\
&< \frac{b-1}{k_1^{(p=0)}}+\frac{(b-1)^2}{k_1^{(p=1)}}+\dots \\
&= \sum_j \frac{(b-1)^{j+1}}{k_1^{(p=j)}},
\end{split}
\end{equation}

but here I can't see how the lat sum can converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume $d \ne 0$. There are $(b-2)(b-1)^{d-1}$ $d$-digit numbers with no $d$'s (as the leading digit is anything but $0$ and $d$), and each is at least $b^{d-1}$, so its reciprocal is at most $b^{1-d}$.  The sum of those reciprocals is at most
$(b-2)\left(\frac{b-1}{b} \right)^{d-1}$.  The sum of this for $d$ from $1$ to $\infty$ is a convergent geometric series.